# How to create a nested object given an array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given is an array like this:

```
var level = ["a", "b", "x"];
```

The output should be:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "x": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
var level = ["a", "b", "x"];
var o = {};
for (var c = 0, len = level.length; c < len; c +=1 ) { 
    var part = level[c]; 
    o[part] = {}; // how to remember the last part?
}
```

How can I remember the last part and add the next level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use a check if the level exist and assign only an object if not set.

```js
function addLevels(levels, object) {
    levels.reduce((o, l) => o[l] = o[l] || {}, object);
}

var object = {};

addLevels(["a", "b", "x"], object);
addLevels(["a", "d", "z"], object);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method by passing an `arrow` function as *argument*.

```js
var level = ["a", "b", "x"];
let result = level.reduceRight((obj, elem) => ({[elem]: obj}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the first good use I've seen for `reduceRight` in a while. Very nice!

Answer (score 12):

Simplest tweak would be to reassign `o` on each iteration:

```js
var level = ["a", "b", "x"];
var o = {};
var initialO = o;
for (var c = 0, len = level.length; c < len; c +=1 ) { 
  var part = level[c];
  o[part] = {};
  o = o[part];
}
console.log(initialO);
```

This might be a clearer way of doing it, though:

```js
const level = ["a", "b", "x"];
const result = {};
level.reduce((accum, key) => {
  accum[key] = {};
  return accum[key];
}, result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one, I think is easiest if you write it in a functional style.

```
var level = ["a", "b", "x"];
var o = {};
level.reduce(function (obj, key) {
    o[key] = {};
    return o[key];
}, o);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with a recursive function

```js
const level = ["a", "b", "x"];
const f = (i) => i === level.length ? {} : {[level[i]]: f(i+1)};
console.log(f(0));
```

Comment: I like this solution as well.